# I want to prove for all $a > 0 $, $b > 0$, $\frac{2ab}{a + b} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)} \geq \frac{a + b}{2} + \sqrt{ab}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

How can I prove that for all $a > 0$ and $b > 0$,  $$\frac{2ab}{a + b}  + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)} \geq \frac{a + b}{2} + \sqrt{ab}$$
I found this inequality in an mathematic olympiade and I could not not prove it.

Answer (score 3):

Rearranging terms and simplifying a bit:
$$
\sqrt{2\left(a^2 + b^2\right)} -2\sqrt{ab}\geq \frac{(a-b)^2}{a+b}
$$
Multiply both sides by $\sqrt{2\left(a^2 + b^2\right)} +2\sqrt{ab}$:$$
2\left(a^2 + b^2\right) -4ab\ge \frac{(a-b)^2}{a+b}(\sqrt{2\left(a^2 + b^2\right)} +2\sqrt{ab})\\
2(a+b)\ge \sqrt{2\left(a^2 + b^2\right)} +2\sqrt{ab}
$$
Square both sides, simplify, square again: $$
4a^2 +8ab + 4b^2\ge 2a^2 + 4ab + 2 b^2 + 4\sqrt{2\left(a^2 + b^2\right)} \sqrt{ab}\\
(a+b)^2 \ge 2\sqrt{2ab\left(a^2 + b^2\right)}\\
(a+b)^4 \ge 8a^3b + 8ab^3 \\
a^4 - 4 a^3b + 6 a^2 b^2 - 4 ab^3 + b^4 \ge 0\\
(a-b)^4 \ge 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that we may assume $b = 1$. (Indeed, divide both sides by $b$ and substitute $a \mapsto ab$.) So, it suffices to establish the following inequality:

$$ \frac{2a}{a+1} + \sqrt{\frac{a^2+1}{2}} \ \stackrel{?}{\geq}\ \frac{a+1}{2} + \sqrt{a} \tag{1} $$

Now let $y = \frac{2\sqrt{a}}{1+a}$, or equivalently, $\frac{1}{y} = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{a} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}})$. Also, note that $0 \leq y \leq 1$. Then

\begin{align*}
\text{(1)}
&\stackrel{\div\sqrt{a}}{\qquad\iff\qquad} y + \sqrt{2y^{-2} - 1} \geq \frac{1}{y} + 1 \\[0.5em]
&\stackrel{\times y}{\qquad\iff\qquad} \sqrt{2-y^2} \geq 1 + y - y^2 \\[0.5em]
&\stackrel{\text{square}}{\qquad\iff\qquad} 2-y^2 \geq (1 + y - y^2)^2 \\[0.5em]
&\qquad\iff\qquad 1 - 2 y + 2 y^3 - y^4 \geq 0 \\[0.5em]
&\qquad\iff\qquad (1-y)^3(1+y) \geq 0,
\end{align*}

which is true because $0 \leq y \leq 1$.

---

**Addendum.** If we define the $p$-norm of the list $\mathbf{x} = (a, b)$ by

$$ \| \mathbf{x} \|_p = \begin{cases}
\bigl( \frac{a^p + b^p}{2} \bigr)^{1/p}, & p \neq 0 \\[0.5em]
\sqrt{ab}, & p = 0
\end{cases}
$$

then $p \mapsto \| \mathbf{x} \|_p$ is an increasing continuous function and the inequality is recast as

$$ \| \mathbf{x} \|_{-1} + \| \mathbf{x} \|_{2} \geq \| \mathbf{x} \|_{1} + \| \mathbf{x} \|_{0}. $$

However, this interpretations doesn't seem providing any useful insight on the problem. (The inflection points of $p \mapsto \| \mathbf{x} \|_p$ are quite non-trivial. So, it is not easy, if not impossible, to invoke some convexity argument.)

Answer (score 0):

This is false in general.

$\dfrac{2ab}{a + b}  + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)} \geq \dfrac{a + b}{2} + \sqrt{ab}
$

If $b=ca$ this is
$\dfrac{2ca^2}{a(1+c)}  + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2(1+c^2)\right)} 
\geq \dfrac{a(1+c)}{2} + \sqrt{ca^2}
$

or
$\dfrac{2c}{1+c}  + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(1+c^2\right)} 
\geq \dfrac{1+c}{2} + \sqrt{c}
$
or
$\dfrac{2c}{1+c}-\dfrac{1+c}{2}  
\geq  \sqrt{c}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(1+c^2\right)}
$

or
$\dfrac{(1-c)^2}{2(1+c)} 
\leq  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(1+c^2\right)}
-\sqrt{c}
$

For $c=2$ this is
$\dfrac{1}{4} 
\leq  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(5\right)}
-\sqrt{2}
\approx 0.1669
$

which is false.

I suspected this result
when I went through the
following series of equivalences
which ended with
something that could be false.

$\dfrac{2ab}{a + b} -\dfrac{a + b}{2}  
\geq  \sqrt{ab}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)}
$

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{(a-b)^2}{2(a+b)}
&\leq  \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)}-\sqrt{ab}\\
&=  (\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)}-\sqrt{ab})\dfrac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)}+\sqrt{ab}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)}+\sqrt{ab}}\\
&=  \dfrac{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)-ab}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)}+\sqrt{ab}}\\
&=  \dfrac{\frac{1}{2}(a-b)^2}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)}+\sqrt{ab}}\\
a+b
&\ge \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)}+\sqrt{ab}\\
(a+b)^2
&\ge \frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)+ab+2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)ab}\\
a^2+2ab+b^2
&\ge \frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2+2ab\right)+2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)ab}\\
\frac12(a^2+2ab+b^2)
&\ge 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2 + b^2\right)ab}\\
\frac14(a+b)^2
&\ge \sqrt{2\left(a^2 + b^2\right)ab}\\
\frac1{16}(a+b)^4
&\ge 2\left(a^2 + b^2\right)ab\\
(a+b)^4
&\ge 32\left(a^2 + b^2\right)ab\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
(a+b)^4
- 32\left(a^2 + b^2\right)ab
&=a^4-28a^3b+6a^2b^2-28ab^3+b^4\\
&=a^4-4a^3b+6a^2b^2-4ab^3+b^4
-24(a^3b+ab^3)\\
&=(a-b)^4
-24ab(a+b)\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
(a-b)^4
&=a^4-4a^3b+6a^2b^2-4ab^3+b^4\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: you have a problem at the line $\frac 14(a+b)^2$ seems you got the $2$ on the right side distributed inside the square root and on the left side at the same time. Conducting the calculation, I get to $\frac 14(a-b)^4$.

Comment: @marty cohen Please can you give specific values of $a,b$ for which the inequality is false?

Comment: @Adam The inequality is true, see my remark. In fact the calculation is $\frac 16$ for $c=2$ not $\frac 14$.